# How to set default cabal directory and other haskell defaults in emacs?

Tags: haskell, emacs, read-eval-print-loop

When I use C-c, C-l to load a haskell source file in emacs, it always prompts me for a cabal directory. I have a sandbox directory that I use for everything atm, is there a way to set that directory as the cabal directory by default so I don't get prompted?

Also, when closing the GHCi repl, it asks me if I want to kill associated buffers. I'd like it to default to "no" without a prompt. How can I set that?

Comment: "it prompts you" - where "it" = "emacs"? No. Certainly it's some kind of Haskell mode for emacs that you (your emacs) has (pre-)installed. Find out which one it is, check its documentation, etc.

Comment: this one? https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/wiki/Haskell-Interactive-Mode-Sessions And you're saying that "It figures out where the cabal directory is" does not find your sandbox? It's a bug then, or a feature request ...

Comment: I don't use the built-in customization utility for Emacs, but that would be one option -- i.e., navigate to the group for the particular library that interests you.  You could do it the old-fashioned way by opening up the source code and looking for entries that begin with `(defcustom . . .` and `(defvar . . .` -- all of those will be variables that can be set to your precise needs, within the guidelines of what the author has already established.  Those variables can generally be changed by having a `(require '...)` library statement before your changes and then each reassignment uses `(setq`